# pushing objects to array in for loop

Tags: javascript, syntax

so i have a problem with some seemingly simple code.
i am trying to calculate the points on a slope of 1/2.
but all I am getting is the empty array object.

```js
const canvas = {
  width: 1200,
  height: 600
};
const slopeValues = [];
for (let i = canvas.height / 2; i < canvas.height / 2; i--) {
  let obj = {};
  obj.x = i;
  slopeValues.push(obj);
}

console.log(slopeValues)
```

I should also mention that I do have the original code structured in a test suite(mocha). that shouldn't effect it but I'm not sure as I'm new to TDD.

Comment: `let i = canvas.height / 2; i < canvas.height` If `i` is initialized to be equal to `canvas.height`, then it will never be `<` than `canvas.height`.

Comment: You are initializing i in the loop as canvas.height / 2, which doesn't meet the condition i < canvas.height / 2. Nothing in the body of the for loop is executed, so slopeValues will be the empty array.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop condition is off. You set `i = height / 2` and set the condition to `i < height / 2`. The condition is already false because 
`(i == height / 2) != (i < height)`

Try this one instead:

```js
const canvas = {
  width: 1200,
  height: 600
};
const slopeValues = [];
for (let i = canvas.height / 2; i >= 0 / 2; i--) {
  let obj = {};
  obj.x = i;
  slopeValues.push(obj);
}

console.log(slopeValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initializing I to be 300, and looping through while i < 300.  That evaluates to false the first time the loop tries to run so the code in the for loop is ignored.